# Reading from COM port

Tags: c

I'm trying to read COM port using the following code,but getting available data on the port  always as zero even when I'm giving input at rs232 port.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *Wfile;
    long size;
    char readport[100];
    if((Wfile = fopen("com1:", "r")) == NULL) // open comport
    {
         printf("port not opened\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fseek(Wfile,0L,SEEK_END);
        size= ftell(Wfile);
        fseek(Wfile,0L,SEEK_SET);
        printf("%ld",size);
        fread(readport,size,1, Wfile);//reading CommunicationString from ComPort
        printf("\n%s",readport);
        fclose(Wfile);}
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You _may_ need to open the port in binary `"rb". You _may_ need to open the port in read/write `"r+". The "r" is for reading, but your comment says "write CommunicationString to ComPort" - tis confusing.   The `fseek()` x2 & `ftell()` are questionable with a com port.  I do not believe you need them and they may cause trouble.  Instead just try to read a byte via fread() and note the function's return value.  BTW: I recommend `fgetc()` instead.

Comment: what about port configuration? there is so much to do here. if you are on windows [read this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2682/Serial-Communication-in-Windows)

Comment: How you are checking the buffer size? You are just checking the size of currently available data on the port. For getting buffer size i think you need to use serial IOCTL

Comment: I tried fgetc() but still the problem continues..

Comment: Actually I'm working on wincc scada and i need to write a script to read from com port , so it is not possible for me to use any OS based header file and also I'm new to this topic...

Comment: As @Koushik said, so much to do  here.  Have you removed the `fseek()`, `ftell()`?  What does you code look like now? When responding to a particular user, use the @name feature.